# Combining a BarChart and Linechart with J free chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Hi im trying to create a chart that is a combination of a bar chart and a line chart in JFree chart. The bar chart is vs time and for each hour it will compare two (or more) different values.

The line chart uses the same scale as the bar chart and shows the overall trend of the data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot each dataset on the same Plot, and use a different renderer for each dataset (for instance a `BarRenderer` and `LineAndShapeRenderer`). Below is a simplified example that generates some mock data values (1-9) and renders the same data as both bars and lines on the same ChartPanel.

```
//Mock data
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
int[] times = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for ( int i = 0; i < times.length; i++ ){
    dataset.addValue(times[i], "Time", "Hour" + String.valueOf(i+1));
}

//create the plot
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot();

//add the first dataset, and render as bar values
CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new BarRenderer();
plot.setDataset(0,dataset);
plot.setRenderer(0,renderer);  

//add the second dataset, render as lines
CategoryItemRenderer renderer2 = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
plot.setDataset(1, dataset);
plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);

//set axis 
plot.setDomainAxis(new CategoryAxis("Time"));
plot.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Value"));
```

And the resulting Chart:

[image: And the results:]

Comment: Hey awesome copeg, this will be extremely useful. Do you happen to know how for the barchart, in lets say your example, how I would add another bar with a different color for each hour. I would post a link but I am not reputable enough yet.

Comment: Add a different `rowkey` to the dataset. Above uses a single rowkey of "Time", but could be many different rowkeys